# Comma characters in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm having issues with comma characters in FabricJS live edit. They just don't show up for some reason...

Characters such as, í, ú, ý, ó etc.

You can try to type and see the issue here: http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/

Is there any javascript genius that knows this issue and how to fix it ?.

Comment: No one has any ideas what could be causing this ?..

Comment: Hi Jack.
Those kind of characters work both in Firefox in Chrome and Internet Explorer 11.
To type them i use an american keyboard on the kitchensink demo you posted.
Ho do you type them? What kind of keyboard do you have? Browser and Operative System.

Answer (score 1):

If you are under windows, with any keyboard you should have no problems.
Under linux and macOSX some characters are not showing ( accented letters for example ) and all the keys that require sequential key combination.

If you are on chinese input method nothing will be entered.
FabricJS team is aware of the issue and is switching from listening the keyup, keypress events to the onInput event that is more realiable for inputing text.

Edit 05/2016:
This actually change in 1.6.1 where both character requiring composition and accents works ( at least on windows ).